# Google maps premier license

Tags: google-maps

I would like to buy Google maps premier license. I tried to contact Google maps through their web site (online inquiry form). No one got back to me.

I would appreciate if someone can help me with this.

Answer (score 1):

From [this page](http://www.google.com/enterprise/earthmaps/maps.html) you can contact their sales department

Comment: I did try through those contact forms. I haven't got a response back yet.